# asp.net c# how to know how many connection object are currently open but not closed by web page

Tags: c#, asp.net

am working on one project which is web based application many developers are used connection object but they are not closed it.

so i can i get the details by webpage that how many connection object are currently used but not closed

am using some code which is mention here

```
protected void btnCheckConnection_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GetIntegratedSecurityConnectionString();
            SetUpPerformanceCounters();          
            CreateConnections();
        }

private static string GetIntegratedSecurityConnectionString()
        {
            string @SqlConn = "Server=190.196.19.12;UID=test1;PWD=test1;Database=test";
            return @SqlConn;
        }  



private void CreateConnections()
    {
        // List the Performance counters.  
        WritePerformanceCounters();

        // Create 4 connections and display counter information.  
        SqlConnection connection1 = new SqlConnection(
              GetIntegratedSecurityConnectionString());
        connection1.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("Opened the 1st Connection:");
        WritePerformanceCounters();

        SqlConnection connection2 = new SqlConnection(
              GetSqlConnectionStringDifferent());
        connection2.Open();
        Response.Write("Opened the 2nd Connection:");
        WritePerformanceCounters();

        SqlConnection connection3 = new SqlConnection(
              GetSqlConnectionString());
        connection3.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("Opened the 3rd Connection:");
        WritePerformanceCounters();

        SqlConnection connection4 = new SqlConnection(
              GetSqlConnectionString());
        connection4.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("Opened the 4th Connection:");
        WritePerformanceCounters();

        connection1.Close();
        Console.WriteLine("Closed the 1st Connection:");
        WritePerformanceCounters();

        connection2.Close();
        Console.WriteLine("Closed the 2nd Connection:");
        WritePerformanceCounters();

        connection3.Close();
        Console.WriteLine("Closed the 3rd Connection:");
        WritePerformanceCounters();

        connection4.Close();
        Console.WriteLine("Closed the 4th Connection:");
        WritePerformanceCounters();
    }


private enum ADO_Net_Performance_Counters
        {
            NumberOfActiveConnectionPools,
            NumberOfReclaimedConnections,
            HardConnectsPerSecond,
            HardDisconnectsPerSecond,
            NumberOfActiveConnectionPoolGroups,
            NumberOfInactiveConnectionPoolGroups,
            NumberOfInactiveConnectionPools,
            NumberOfNonPooledConnections,
            NumberOfPooledConnections,
            NumberOfStasisConnections,
            NumberOfFreeConnections
            // The following performance counters are more expensive to track.  
            // Enable ConnectionPoolPerformanceCounterDetail in your config file.  
            //     SoftConnectsPerSecond  
            //     SoftDisconnectsPerSecond  
            //     NumberOfActiveConnections  

        }



  private void SetUpPerformanceCounters()
        {
            connection.Close();
            this.PerfCounters = new PerformanceCounter[11];
            string instanceName = GetInstanceName();
            testInstanceName = instanceName;
            Type apc = typeof(ADO_Net_Performance_Counters);
            int i = 0;
            foreach (string s in Enum.GetNames(apc))
            {
                this.PerfCounters[i] = new PerformanceCounter();
                this.PerfCounters[i].CategoryName = ".NET Data Provider for SqlServer";
                this.PerfCounters[i].CounterName = s;
                this.PerfCounters[i].InstanceName = instanceName;
                i++;
            }
        }
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern int GetCurrentProcessId();


private string GetInstanceName()
        {
            //This works for Winforms apps.  
            /*
            string instanceName =
                System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Name;
                */
            //This works for Web apps.  

            //string instanceName = System.Environment.UserDomainName; //System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Name;
            string instanceName = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().GetName().Name;

            // Must replace special characters like (, ), #, /, \\  
            string instanceName2 =
                AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName.ToString().Replace('(', '[')
                .Replace(')', ']').Replace('#', '_').Replace('/', '_').Replace('\\', '_');

            // For ASP.NET applications your instanceName will be your CurrentDomain's   
            // FriendlyName. Replace the line above that sets the instanceName with this:  
            // instanceName = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName.ToString().Replace('(','[')  
            // .Replace(')',']').Replace('#','_').Replace('/','_').Replace('\\','_');  

            string pid = GetCurrentProcessId().ToString();
            instanceName = instanceName + "[" + pid + "]";
            Console.WriteLine("Instance Name: {0}", instanceName);
            Console.WriteLine("---------------------------");
            return instanceName;
        }

  private void WritePerformanceCounters()
        {
            foreach (PerformanceCounter p in this.PerfCounters)
            {    
                string strName = p.CounterName + " = " + p.NextValue();    
            }    
        }
```

if amusing **p.NextValue()** then  facing error that **Additional information: Instance 'Dummy_Project[9544]' does not exist in the specified Category.**

Comment: Connections should be closed as soon as the data has been read/processed and not left open. SqlConnection also implements iDisposable so you should always use using-statement with for proper memory cleanup.

Answer (score 1):

In a web application, always close the connection as soon as you're done with it. Tell all other developers on your team to do the same.

You need to wrap your calls in using statement (or try...catch if you wish to handle the exceptions), and it will close it and dispose it automatically.
  
That will not really close the connection. It will just return it to the connections pool, and next time you try to open a new connection (within a short time), you will actually be given a connection from the pool. This will significantly enhance the performance and allow your application to scale up better.

Comment: absolutely you are right currently all developers are follow the same but what we can do for previous code

Comment: Go back and fix it. Otherwise how are you planning to close all those connections? And what if there are exceptions? In high traffic hours, your application will go down on its knees.

Comment: developers are closed connection but some connection are not closed so can you give some ideas how we can identity that where is the connection are not closed.

Comment: Oh, you're trying to find if there is any code still opening the connection without closing it, so you can fix it? I'm afraid your only way is to search for all instance of `SqlConnection` and review the code to see if it was properly closed. I don't know if there is any tool that can help you with that from the application side. You can do it on the database side using profiler, but that can be hard because you'll need to test your entire application.

Comment: absolutely you got it what am try to saying

Comment: best way i discoverd to prevent open connections was to write my own sqlconnection class in which the conection gets opened and closed and returns a Datatable from the query string.